# Is it possible to run OpenVR code on an HTC Vive without SteamVR?

Tags: virtual-reality, steam, steamvr, openvr

I wrote some code to track controller poses using OpenVR. The problem is that SteamVR is generally very annoying to have running in the background.

I tried to switch to OpenXR. The Problem seems to be the runtime to interface with the HTC Vive (also SteamVR in the case of using OpenXR). Is there any runtime alternative without such a bloated interface? Something that wouldn't require me to have a steam account or graphics card (I'm just planning on tracking controller poses so I see it as kind of unpractical to have to require extra computing power).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.